# Will OpenGL release the part of BO after glInvalidBufferSubData()?

Tags: opengl

For example,I have a BO called `bo_vertex` with 4*4 vertex data,first I render all the vertexes , then I only need the first four vertexes for next frame, so I invalidate the data after four vertexes.Now what will OpenGL do to the part specified in `glInvalidateBufferSubData()`? If I need a BO for 16 vertexes data again, can I reuse `bo_vertex` directly,or should call glBufferData() to reallocate the storage for `bo_vertex`?

Comment: Yes,I made a mistake, glInvalidateBufferData() here should be glInvalidateBufferSubData(). Document says **the content of the specified range of the buffer's data store becomes undefined**,I want to know the memory of invalidated part is available or not after call glInvalidateBufferSubData(), or OpenGL release the part memory makes it illegal to use it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth reading the original extension specification for this [ARB_invalidate_subdata](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_invalidate_subdata.txt). Invalidating a buffer object (or a region of it) as well as a framebuffer object attachment or a texture region will not "shrink" the size of the respective resource. It is only for signaling to the OpenGL implementation that a particular (sub)region of that resource is not to *survive* across multiple memory barriers that the OpenGL driver inserts automatically between OpenGL calls writing to and/or reading from those resources. It is very much like the explicit Vulkan memory barriers, however OpenGL was always thought to do this automatically and in most cases OpenGL had to be conservative when guessing whether the user still needed a resource across certain boundaries (like a swapbuffers).

With ARB_invalidate_subdata it is intended that a user/client application can *hint* to the OpenGL driver that certain memory barriers do not need to be inserted into the command stream to e.g. move memory from on-chip framebuffer or local memory to other memory regions intended for different accesses to those resources.

Comment: It seems the most benefit for these functions is to improve the efficiency if I need to translate data in buffer objects.If so, what is the benefit of **glInvalidateBufferData()**? If all data is invalidated ,why not delete it?